# $\sum_n(-1)^n\int_Xf_n \, d\mu=\int_X\sum_n(-1)^nf_n \, d\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, sequence-of-function

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be measure space, $(f_n)_n$ be a non-increasing sequence of functions in $L^1(\mu)$, converging $\mu$-a.e to $0.$

Prove that $$\sum_n(-1)^n\int_Xf_n \, d\mu=\int_X\sum_n(-1)^nf_n \, d\mu.$$

To prove it, it's evident that we should use the dominated convergence theorem on $\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kf_k:$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\int_Xf_k \, d\mu=\int_X\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kf_k \, d\mu$$
Since $(f_n)_n$ is a non-increasing sequence converging $\mu$-a.e to $0$ (which means $f_n$ are non-negative $\mu$-a.e), this shows that $(\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kf_k)_n$ converges $\mu$-a.e (to $\sum_n(-1)^nf_n$), it remains to prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kf_k$ is dominated by a function $\phi \in L^1.$

Do you know how to have a verification?

Comment: What is your dominating function?

Comment: Having problem to find one

Comment: @Kurt.W.X. Notice that if $S(x)=\sum_n(-1)^{n+1}f_x(x)$ and $S_n$ is the corresponding $n$-th partial sum, $$|S-S_n|=(-1)^n(S-S_n)\leq f_{n+1}\leq \ldots \leq f_1$$

Comment: Perhaps $f_1$ would work?

Comment: Delayed response, was just guiding the OP rather than answering.

Comment: How to prove that $\sum_n(-1)^{n+1}f_n \in L^1$

Comment: The partial sums are in $L_1$. The integrability of the limit is dominated convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0\leq f_{n+1}\leq f_n$, we have that $S=\sum_n(-1)^{n+1}f_n$ converges $\mu$-al,ost surele. Also, by well known properties of alternating series with nondecreasing terms we have that

$$ 
|S-S_n|=(-1)^n(S-S_n)\leq f_{n+1}\leq\ldots\leq f_1
$$
By dominated convergence

1. $\|S-S_n\|_1\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.
2. $S\in L_1$ since   $|S|\leq |S-S_n|+f_{n+1}$.
3. $\int S\,d\mu = \sum_n(-1)^{n+1}\int f_n\,d\mu$

Comment: So, we can say that $|\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kf_k| \leq f_1$

Comment: Can you provide the inequalities for alternating series?

Comment: @Kurt.W.X: Look at Apostol's Analysis book  p. 188 for a derivation. The main ideas is to write $(-1)^n(S-S_n) = f_{n+1}-(f_{n+2}-f_{n+3})-\ldots \leq f_{n+1}$