# $\sum_n\int_Xf_n\phi_nd\mu=\int_X\sum_n\phi_nf_n d\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space, $(f_n)_n$ be a monotone sequence of $L^1(\mu),$ converging $\mu$-a.e to $0,$ $(\phi_n)_n$ a sequence of functions such that $$\exists p>0;\forall n \in \mathbb{N},|\sum_{k=1}^n\phi_k| \leq p \  \ \mu-a.e.$$

Prove that $$\sum_n\int_Xf_n\phi_nd\mu=\int_X\sum_n\phi_nf_n d\mu$$

A particular case [$\phi_n=(-1)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806608/sum-n-1n-int-xf-nd-mu-int-x-sum-n-1nf-nd-mu/3806628#3806628) is proved.

What domination do you suggest this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summation by parts gives

$$
\Big|\sum^n_{k=1}f_k\phi_k\Big|\leq |\Phi_n|f_{n+1} + \sum^n_{k=1}|\Phi_k||f_{k+1}-f_k|
\leq p|f_{n+1}|+p(f_1-f_{n+1})
$$
where $\Phi_k=\sum^k_{j=1}\phi_j$. You can then use dominated convergence